# Joomla 3.0: Change favicon, no showing in chrome and Safari

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a problem with change favicon on my web project.
Change favicon, i see with Mozilla, but problem with showing in chrome and safari.I do not know what or where to change?My favicon is format "ico"
Please help

Comment: where is your favicon file located?

Comment: My favicon fail is directory on my template  /templateName/favicon.ico

Comment: This is  test favicon show in Mozila, but problem chrome and Safari http://www.uts.bg/templates/theme3289/favicon.ico

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome refer this.

Answer (score 2):

Favicons are cached aggressively by browsers, so you'll continue to see the previous favicon unless you delete the browser cache. You can quickly check if that is the case by visiting from another machine that didn't visit the site previously.

Comment: I any more remove cash on my computer or another PC, but problem is no fix

Comment: Then it's impossible to say without a link to your site.

Comment: This favicon no problem with Mozila, this icon no show with Safari and Chrome

Comment: Yes, you said that already. It's impossible to say why without seeing the site…

Comment: Specifically load the image in your browser to reload it.  http://www.mysite.com/templateName/favicon.ico . Then go back to website and reload site.